# Polars Element Wise List Operations using Another Column

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm seeking an expression which will give each element of a group in a list following some operation across columns

For example given the dataframe

```
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
    }
)
```

I want to have an expression that gives the output:

```
┌─────┬───────┬────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ output         │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]      │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ [0, 1, 2, 3]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2     ┆ [-1, 0, 2, 3]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ [-2, -1, 0, 1] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 4     ┆ [-3, -2, -1, 0]│
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ [0, 1, 2]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ [-1, 0, 1]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ [-2, -1, 0]    │
└─────┴───────┴────────────────┘
```

This is the list of all elements in group id subtract the `value` column. In reality, I would not like to subtract but rather try several different aggregations for an ML model.

For this particular example, I tried:

```
df.with_column(pl.col("value").list().over("id").arr.eval(pl.element() - pl.col("value")).alias("output"))
```

For some reason when doing this, I end up with all zeros. When trying to debug, I found that replacing the subtraction with multiplication and I get all squares. What am I doing wrong?

Again, any response is highly appreciated so thanks in advance.

EDIT: Initially I had the wrong example output values, corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to do this with `explode`, then grouping back the columns together.

Here is how to do it:

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        output = pl.col('value').implode().over('id'))
    .explode('output')
    .with_columns(
        output = pl.col('output') - pl.col('value')
    )
    .groupby(pl.all().exclude('output'), maintain_order=True).all()
)

# Result
┌─────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ output        │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ [0, 1, … 3]   │
│ 1   ┆ 2     ┆ [-1, 0, … 2]  │
│ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ [-2, -1, … 1] │
│ 1   ┆ 4     ┆ [-3, -2, … 0] │
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ [0, 1, 2]     │
│ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ [-1, 0, 1]    │
│ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ [-2, -1, 0]   │
└─────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

If the final order does not matter to you, you can remove `maintain_order`, that will make the calculation faster.

I do not believe it is possible to do this without exploding the output column first

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate the "combinations" is to `.join` the dataframe with itself. (*"self join"*)

Adding `row_nr` allows you to `.groupby`

```
df.with_columns(
   df.join(df.with_row_count(), on="id")
     .groupby("row_nr", maintain_order=True)
     .agg(
        output = pl.col("value") - pl.col("value_right")
     )
)
```

```
shape: (7, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬────────┬─────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ row_nr ┆ output          │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---             │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ u32    ┆ list[i64]       │
╞═════╪═══════╪════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 0      ┆ [0, 1, 2, 3]    │
│ 1   ┆ 2     ┆ 1      ┆ [-1, 0, 1, 2]   │
│ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ 2      ┆ [-2, -1, 0, 1]  │
│ 1   ┆ 4     ┆ 3      ┆ [-3, -2, -1, 0] │
│ 2   ┆ 1     ┆ 4      ┆ [0, 1, 2]       │
│ 2   ┆ 2     ┆ 5      ┆ [-1, 0, 1]      │
│ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ 6      ┆ [-2, -1, 0]     │
└─────┴───────┴────────┴─────────────────┘
```